# Multiple clients access to single WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, wcf, endpoint

Sorry if this was asked before but I've been searching the answer to my problem for two days.
I used the very nice tuto on WCF programming chat application [here](http://badger.developpez.com/tutoriels/dotnet/chatez-avec-WCF/) and I have done the same on my solution on VS except the client application which is not WPF for me but an ASP.Net web application.

I succeed running my app on localhost for one client. That's fine.
Then I want to simulate an other connection from user and open a new page (on a new browser). The new user connected is the new "owner" of the service and replace the other one on the first window. So I can't simulate two users on the chat.

I was searching on dynamic WFC endpoints without success.

On my MVC controller, I've got :

```
channelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IChat>(this, "configClient");
_chat = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

and in my config file :

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IChat">

        <security mode="None"/>
         </binding>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8740/Service1.svc" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IChat" contract="ChatClassLibrary.Interfaces.IChat"
        name="configClient">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="alexandre" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <services>
      <service name="ChatClassLibrary.Chat">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IChat" contract="ChatClassLibrary.Interfaces.IChat" name="configClient"/>
      </service>
    </services>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: What do you need dynamic endpoints for ??? WCF services are designed to be accessible via multiple clients , just host it in a server where it can be accessible to those clients

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually I have add the WCF service in my ASP.Net project. Then configure it at startup page (and the asp.net project as startup project). I run everything on brower Chrome (http://localhost:8740/).
Then I run the same adress on Firefox to see if I can join the same service with a second user but it doesn't work (listUsers = 1 with the new user. I expect listUsers=2 as said on the tuto but it doesn't work...).

Comment: I believe you're using web sockets , it must be a problem with the code then , since you're actually getting a response from your service

Comment: Thanks. I want to add that the WCF Test client window shows me the dedicated method but I can't click on them with the message : "This operation is not supported on WCF Test Client". Perhaps it is related to this problem ?

Comment: Perhaps I have an issue in the code.
As I said, I use MVC design pattern for my ASP.Net web site.
For the ChatController, I assume that there is one controller per session right ? If that's true, I added a static List<Message> list to handle all user messages.
Then, using the callback function of WCF, I return the message sent and put it in my static List<Message>. Then I update this list to show it on the webpage, at each message sent.

On the two browsers, the listMessage is a new one for each session newly created...